# Python cross multiplication with an arbitrary number of lists

Tags: python

I'm not sure what the correct term is for the multiplication here but I need to multiply an element from List A for example by every element in List B and create a new list for the new elements, so that the total length of the new list is len(A)*len(B).

As an example

```
A = [1,3,5], B=[4,6,8]
```

I need to multiply the two together to get

```
C = [4,6,8,12,18,24,20,30,40]
```

I have researched this and I have found that itertools(product) have exactly what I needed, however it is for a specific number of lists and I need to generalise to any number of lists as requested by the user.

I don't have access to the full code right now but the code asks the user for some lists (can be any number of lists) and the lists can have any number of elements in the lists (but all lists contain the same number of elements). These lists are then stored in one big list.

For example (user input)

```
A = [2,5,8], B= [4,7,3]
```

The big list will be

```
C = [[2,5,8],[4,7,3]]
```

In this case there are two lists in the big list but in general it can be any number of lists.

Once the code has this I have

```
print([a*b for a,b in itertools.product(C[0],C[1])])
>> [8,14,6,20,35,15,32,56,24]
```

The output of this is exactly what I want, however in this case the code is written for exactly two lists and I need it generalised to n lists.

I've been thinking about creating a loop to somehow loop over it n times but so far I have not been successful in this. Since C could any of any length then the loop needs a way to know when it's reached the end of the list. I don't need it to compute the product with n lists at the same time

```
print([a0*a1*...*a(n-1) for a0,a1,...,a(n-1) in itertools.product(C[0],C[1],C[2],...C[n-1])])
```

The loop could multiply two lists at a time then use the result from that multiplication against the next list in C and so on until C[n-1].

I would appreciate any advice to see if I'm at least heading in the right direction.

p.s. I am using numpy and the lists are arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass variable number of arguments to `itertools.product` with `*`. `*` is the unpacking operator that unpacks the list and passes its values the values of list to the function as if they are separately passed.

```
import itertools
import math

A = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]

result = list(map(math.prod, itertools.product(*A)))
print(result)
```

Result:

```
[15, 18, 20, 24, 30, 36, 40, 48]
```

---

You can find many explanations on the internet about `*` operator. In short, if you call a function like `f(*lst)`, it will be roughly equivalent to `f(lst[0], lst[1], ..., lst[len(lst) - 1])`. So, it will save you from the need to know the length of the list.

Edit: I just realized that `math.prod` is a 3.8+ feature. If you're running an older version of Python, you can replace it with its numpy equivalent, `np.prod`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [reduce function](https://realpython.com/python-reduce-function/) that is intended exactly for these types of operations, which is based on recursion and accumulation. I am providing you an example with a primitive function so you can better understand its functionality:

```
lists = [
    [4, 6, 8],
    [1, 3, 5]
]


def reduce(function, iterable, initializer=None):
    it = iter(iterable)
    if initializer is None:
        value = next(it)
    else:
        value = initializer
    for element in it:
        value = function(value, element)
    return value


def cmp(a, b):
    for x in a:
        for y in b:
            yield x*y


summed = list(reduce(cmp, lists))

# OUTPUT

[4, 12, 20, 6, 18, 30, 8, 24, 40]
```

In case you need it sorted just make use of the [sort() function](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-list-sort/).